# jQuery selector syntax gives Firefox warning

Tags: jquery, firefox, syntax, append, warnings

The following code

```
stringref = "tab_2";
jQuery('.someclass a:not(.someclass #a_someclass_'+stringref+')').css('color', '#000');
```

gives me this warning in the FF 3.5.5 error console and I can't figure out why:

`Warning: Missing closing ')' in negation pseudo-class '#a_someclass_tab_2'.`

Is my syntax failing me or has FF gone bonkers ?

Comment: I don't see a problem with it. And seems to work perfectly well in FF 3.5.6: http://jsbin.com/aroli (editable via http://jsbin.com/aroli/edit#javascript)

Comment: I don't get any warnings on FF 3.5.6 with your code snippet.

Comment: Wow, that's a really good resource to know! I never knew jsbin existed... (and confirmed working in Opera, for all the good that will do).

Comment: You were all on the right track, thank you all for the prompt help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your selector is too complex -- I don't think spaces are allowed within a `:not()` pseudoclass. Are you trying to match `a` descendants of `.someclass` that do not have the given ID? If so, just remove the `.someclass` within the `:not()`.

Comment: I agree, it works AFAIK, but it is a bit convoluted. I would do it this way: `jQuery('.someclass a').not('#a_someclass_' + stringref + ')').css('color, '#000');`

Comment: quote from the docs "As of jQuery 1.3 :not() also support selectors separated by commas and complex selectors, for example: :not(div a) and :not(div,a)." http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not

Comment: Figures, as usually I'm looking for possible issues in the wrong place. That did the trick, Dave :D Much appreciated, thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Firefox (3.5.6) indeed does throw a Warning (***if you are not seeing it in Firebug, it's because you do not have 'Show CSS Errors' enabled*** - see Firebug Console tab).

Firefox is, in a false positive way, parsing the jQuery selector syntax as non-compliant CSS. It is safe to ignore this FF warning (it's not an error remember).

Answer (score 2):

I second Dave in that it is most likely the space in your selector.

The :not() syn­tax in jQuery is enhan­ced, com­pa­red to the CSS stan­dard, so it appears that the parser puts out a war­ning since it checks for CSS com­pliance only.

Comment: @brianpeiris It's not actually an error, its a warning. So make sure you have that enabled.  There is not actually an issue with his code, it is a false positive picked up by the parser.

Comment: You're right. I did some digging; jQuery defaults to document.querySelectorAll in FF so running this: `document.querySelectorAll('.someclass a:not(.someclass #a_someclass_tab_2)');` gives you an exception *and* a warning. jQuery then resorts to Sizzle to complete the selection.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax looks to be fine, and didn't give me any errors. But I would simplify it a bit, which should help you avoid mis-fired warnings.

```
var stringref = "tab_2";
jQuery('a.someclass:not(#a_someclass_'+stringref+')').css('color', '#000');
```